# Python - .pop() works on 2nd to last item instead of last

Tags: python

I'm trying to pop certain items from a list: 5th from last, that last, and the first and appending them to a new list. However, using .pop() and .pop(0) will pop the 2nd to last and 2nd items instead.

```
def word_mixer(orig_list):
    orig_list.sort()
    new_list = []
    while len(orig_list) > 5:
        orig_list.pop(-4)
        new_list.append(orig_list.pop(-4))
        orig_list.pop(0)
        new_list.append(orig_list.pop(0))
        orig_list.pop()
        new_list.append(orig_list.pop())
    return new_list

poem = input("Give me a poem: ")
poem_list = poem.split()
poem_list_len = len(poem_list)
for item in range(poem_list_len):
    if len(poem_list[item]) <= 3:
        print(poem_list[item].lower())
    elif len(poem_list[item]) >= 7:
        print(poem_list[item].upper())
    else:
        print(poem_list[item])
word_mixer(poem_list)
```

Given the list [a b c d e f g h i j k] returns ['g', 'b', 'j'] instead of ['g', 'a', 'k']. Why is it behaving this way?

Comment: you are popping then trying to append....that is the issue

Comment: `pop(-4)` pops the fourth from last, not fifth.  Are you also aware that `pop()` *remove* items from a list?  I'm not clear why you `pop()` twice in each case...

Comment: `orig_list.pop(-4)` followed by `new_list.append(orig_list.pop(-4))` is popping two *different* items from the list - and the first popped item is being discarded.

Comment: ok, I understand now: I removed the orig_list.pop() lines and just have new_list.append(org_list.pop()), it works now. Thank you for the comments!